# Number of ways to split a number in to m parts with each part having constraint

Tags: combinatorics

I have a constraint table `k` of length m.

And i need to find out number of ways to split a number n in to m parts where each part `i` should have the following range of [1, k<sub>i</sub>].

1 <= n <= 10<sup>7</sup>

1 <= max(k) <= 50

Yes order matters.

Comment: Integer partitions are hard. Your problem probably does not have a neat solution. Perhaps you can provide more context about why you need it. How big is $n$? Do you need an algorithm? A formula?

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes any algorithm will be appreciated.

Comment: You could write a recursive algorithm to calculate the number you want. For $n=10^7$ the answer will be very very large.

Comment: @EthanBolker can you explain more about the recursive function and how to do it. All my calculations will be done under prime modulo.

Comment: You've now added a condition. Please edit the question to include a worked out example showing the list of ways. It should be small enough to do by hand but large enough to show the interesting features. Maybe $n=5$ and $m=3$ will be large enough. Don't try to put it in a comment.